# Sending mail with Python's smtplib returns "501 5.1.3 Invalid address"

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

Consider this code extract:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

body = "some content"

email = EmailMessage()
email.set_content(body, subtype='html')   

to = "you@work.com"
email['From'] = "me@work.com"
email['To'] = to
email['Cc'] = ""
email['Bcc'] = ""
email['Subject'] = "Hello"

smtp_connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.work.com", 25)  
status = smtp_connection.send_message(email)
print(str(status))
print(to)
```

When running the code, the mail actually arrives correctly at the destination, but the print statement returns this: `{'': (501, b'5.1.3 Invalid address')}`

I've seen other posts around on the internet with similar error message, where it's been a case of malformed recipient addresses causing the message not to be delivered, but in my case the emails actually do get delivered correctly. I've also made sure that the email address output'ed by the last print statement is actually correct.

Any input on how to debug this further will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer. Looks like empty "CC" and "BCC" values causes the error. When I removed these I got rid of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Cc` and `Bcc` is also empty, it is no need to attach it in `email[]`